# AndEngine GLES 2.0 - Power button issue - Game not Resume After unlock Screen

Tags: android, andengine

I'm developing an android game using AndEngine GLES 2.0. Some of my users face such problem: after locking/unlocking device or after pressing home button and resuming the game not working completely means game hang after unlock screen. I mean this happens after calling onResume and onPause.

my onPause code is

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    this.mEngine.stop();
    this.getSManager().stop(Sounds.SPIN);
    dbHelper.close();
}
```

onResuam Code is:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() 
{

 if (this.mEngine.isRunning()) 
    {
        this.getSManager().stop(Sounds.SPIN);
        this.mEngine.stop();
    }
    else 
    {
        this.mEngine.start();
    }

}
```

anyone having idea about it ? please suggest some solution for this issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenLayout|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
```

To your main activity.

Also: make sure none of your textures are Static vars. Don't know why, but using static vars for textures hoses the engine on resume.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I've fixed it by reloading all the textures & fonts in Activity's `OnResume` method.

**EDIT** to answer Plastic Surgeon :

I have a class `TextureCache` that is caching the textures. It was working ok, but on application resume all the texture would become black. As you said, it seems to be an issue with static variables. I've added a method `clear` that clears the static data, and I call it when the application resumes.

Here is my class :

```
public class TextureCache {
private static Map<String, ITextureRegion> textures = new HashMap<String, ITextureRegion>();
private static Context ctx;
private static TextureManager tm;

public static void clear() {
    textures.clear();
}


public static void init(Context pCtx, TextureManager pTm) {
    ctx = pCtx;
    tm = pTm;
}


public static ITextureRegion getTexture(String name) {
    ITextureRegion texture = textures.get(name);
    if (texture == null) {
        BitmapFactory.Options opt = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        opt.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        try {
            InputStream in = ctx.getResources().getAssets().open("gfx/" + name);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, opt);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("TextureCache", "Could not load texture [" + name + "]", e);
        }
        BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");
        BitmapTextureAtlas texAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(tm, opt.outWidth, opt.outHeight, TextureOptions.DEFAULT);
        texture = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(texAtlas, ctx, name, 0, 0);
        texture1.load();    
        textures.put(name, texture);
    }
    return texture;
}
}
```

I call the method `clear` in Activity's `onResume` :

```
@Override
protected synchronized void onResume() {
    TextureCache.clear();
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: This also looks like a good solution. Would you mind posting some code when you have a second?